# html4 video embed

Tags: embed, html4

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<embed width="420" height="345" src="video.wmv" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to embed a video in html page, video file is in local folder and that is of wmv format. Its not working. I have used the above mentioned code.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538724/how-to-embed-wmv-files-in-my-html-file

Comment: Why do you write a page with an XHTML doctype and call it HTML 4?

Comment: its only working in IE8, not working in other browser, how to recover that thing

Answer (score 1):

Convert video to SWF format by using any Converter. Then give link of that video. It'll work