# Windows Media Player Embed Object not get active on Mozilla

Tags: html, firefox, windows-media-player

I have used following object tag for embed windows media player on web page to play video.

```
<object type="video/x-ms-wmv" data="http://www.educationalquestions.com/video/ELL_PART_5_768k.wmv" width="320" height="255">
  <param name="src" value="http://www.educationalquestions.com/video/ELL_PART_5_768k.wmv">
  <param name="autoStart" value="0">
</object>
```

at first time the player is not visible. after navigate the window the player is getting activate. Check for [Demo](http://jsbin.com/oqehuc/28) and the [Demo code](http://jsbin.com/oqehuc/28/edit).

Please suggest to activate the player at execution time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538724/how-to-embed-wmv-files-in-my-html-file

Comment: @sureshunivers what is the problem exactly? it is working fine for me in all browsers (chrome,safari,opera,firefox,IE)

Comment: @Thanos thanks for your replay. It is not working on Mozilla Firefox browser 22.0 version

Comment: That's because you haven't installed any video player add ons on your Mozilla Browser.

Answer (score 0):

its working fine in firefox latest edition thing is when you use code like above to embed browser use media plugins installed in system to display media player and for video playback.

For example in my system i have vlc installed when i launch your demo in firefox it shows vlc media player and played your video smoothly.