# Video Player in MVC2 Application

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2

i need to embed a video player in .net mvc application. there are few requirements need to be satisfy

> 1. support .flv, .mp4, .wmp formats.
> 2. able to load videos(user can select video)

what kind of player can be used.

> there are few questions i need to understand.
>
> 1. what's wrong with normal video tag.
> 2. what about html5 video players
> 3. any external libraries can be used.

Answer (score 0):

As MVC renders html, You'll find numerous resources online of how to do this in HTML:
Some are the resources given as:

- http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=622&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1
- http://www.walkernews.net/2008/08/17/windows-media-player-how-to-embed-wmv-file-in-html-code/
- [how to embed WMV files in my html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538724/how-to-embed-wmv-files-in-my-html-file)