# How can I play wmv video in HTML player?

Tags: html, html5-video, wmv

I want to Play `wmv` video in browser, and place header and footer in the page. I am unable to play `mp4` video, but I want to play `wmv`. I google it but unable to find anything. Kindly guide me ho to play `wmv` video from HTML page.

Comment: You cannot play WMV video file in HTML5 video. Have a look at my answer. BTW you are able to play MP4 file right? I think there is a typo in your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play wmv files in html5 video player](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459891/how-to-play-wmv-files-in-html5-video-player)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot play WMV files in HTML5 video. This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459891/how-to-play-wmv-files-in-html5-video-player).

If you want to play video cross browser with HTML5 video you have to transcode your WMV file (currently to MP4 and WebM). 
Have a look here for a take on [HTML5 video](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html).

To embed WMV videos in a web page you have to use an object/embed tag that calls the windows media player plugin (if it is installed - ie it will not work in platforms where the plugin is not available like iOS). Have a look here for a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538724/how-to-embed-wmv-files-in-my-html-file).

Answer (score -3):

For MP4

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

For WMV

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.wmv" type="video/wmv">
</video>
```

Replace the movie.xxx part with the name or link/name of your movie
You can place this anywhere on your page

Comment: This is wrong for HTML5 video: have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459891/how-to-play-wmv-files-in-html5-video-player)