# Play a sound file store in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a little game on website for english learner using PHP and mySQL, my table pronunciation in database will look like this

```
word_id | spelling | sound

1         school     school.wma
```

when the sound school.wma is played, users need to type "school" correctly in the textbox, so how to play a sound file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260092/how-can-i-play-wmv-video-in-html-player

Comment: For starters, that "school.wma" is just the *file name*, right? Or is the actual binary data stored in the database somewhere?

Comment: @deceze its a wma file name "school" that I will upload it to my own mysql database

Comment: Why would you store a sound file in a database? Try just storing the files data (eg name, location, etc) and use that to locate the file on the disk, then load that into PHP and change headers to reflect that. Then call the PHP file from your HTML.

Comment: @KalebKlein yeah how foolish of me, i just figured out a while ago. Thank you for your answer

Comment: MySQL gives you the option to store blob data, but it can become conversion and can cause huge server load making the query for the data. It's best to store meta data then use that to locate and load the file. Then it can easily be done asynchronously.

Comment: @KalebKlein yeah true, I will only store name, id and the path to the stored place on server in MySQL. You can post your answer and I will mark as a thank you in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL gives you the option to store blob data, but it can become cumbersome and can cause huge server load making the query for the data. It's best to store meta data then use that to locate and load the file. Then it can easily be done asynchronously.