# Windows Media Player in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-media-player, wmplib

First attempt at this: I created the Windows Media Player programmatically by adding the WMPLib as a reference in my project. I am trying to play a playlist using Windows Media Player in a ASP.Net web page (Visual Studio 2015). I cannot use the video tag used in examples for HTML 5 as I need to display .wmv, .mp4, .jpg formats in the control. When I run the code, no errors are displayed and I see an empty browser, what am I missing?
Here is my sample code:

```
    WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer Player;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileNames();            
    }

    public void FileNames()
    {
        String[] extentions = { "*.wmv", "*.mp4", "*.jpg" };
        List<string> files = new List<string>();
        foreach (string filter in extentions)
        {
            files.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Documents\", filter));
        }   

        foreach (string ss in files)
        {
            String name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(ss);
            Player = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();

            WMPLib.IWMPPlaylist playList = Player.newPlaylist("myPlayList", "");
            playList.appendItem(Player.newMedia(name));
            Player.currentPlaylist = playList;
            Player.controls.play();
        }
    }
```

I am aware of the hard coded path which is not good practice, however I just need to get this displaying on my local machine.
Thanks!

Comment: Of course your code will open a WMP on your machine, but how should it when accessing your page from a browser? The code you wrote just happens server-side.

Comment: Thanks Fliburt, so how do I get it to work? I tried something in the line of "Page.Controls.Add(Player);", what would be the correct implementation of this?

Comment: You can't add a windows control. See [How can i Play wmv video in HTML player?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23260092/205233) for answers on how to get this to work.

Comment: I got that working - thanks a lot Filburt! Problem is I have to play an list of files, so using a loop I can add those files to the player BUT because the for loop completes execution only the last file is played in the browser. I understand why this happens, I don't know how to pause in order for the player to finish showing the current file before moving on the next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After two more weeks of research we managed to come up with a solution by toggling between different types of controls based on the content that needs to be displayed. To display PowerPoint slideshows, we converted all slides to images and then looped through the collection. Here is a snippet of the code in case someone else needs a bit of guidance with a similar issue:

```
 <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <%-- Video DIV --%>
    <div runat="server" id="VidDiv" class="fullscreen-bg">
    </div>
    <%-- IMAGE DIV --%>
    <div runat="server" id="container">
        <div runat="server" id="containers">
        </div>
        <%-- this is where the code gets dynamically created --%>
    </div>
</form>
 </body>
   <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
  <script id="CallMyFunction" type="text/javascript">
          var index = 1;
    document.getElementById("VidDiv").style.display = "none";

var ImageCount = 1;
autoSlide();

function autoSlide() {

    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("Images");
    var video_player = document.getElementsByClassName("fullscreen-bd__video");
    var count;
    var video;
    var videoSource = new Array(), vids, i;

    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    if (index > x.length) {
        index = 1
    }

    x[index - 1].style.display = "block";

    count = x.length;

    if (ImageCount <= count) {
        index++;
        ImageCount = 1 + ImageCount;
        setTimeout(autoSlide, 8000);
    }
    else {
        //this is where we should switch from image div to video div 
        document.getElementById("container").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("VidDiv").style.display = "block";

        //create a counter to check the number of video tags
        video = document.getElementsByTagName('video'), numVideos = video.length;

        for (i = 0; i < numVideos; i++) {

            videoSource[i] = video.item(i).src;
            document.getElementById("myVideo" + i).style.display = "none";
        }

        var videoCount = 0;
        if (videoCount <= numVideos -1) {

            function videoPlay(videoNum) {
                if (videoCount > 0)
                {
                    document.getElementById("myVideo" + (videoCount - 1)).style.display = "none";
                }
                document.getElementById("myVideo" + videoCount).style.display = "block";

                document.getElementById("myVideo" + videoCount).setAttribute("src", "" + videoSource[videoCount] + "");
                document.getElementById("myVideo" + videoCount).load();
                document.getElementById("myVideo" + videoCount).play();
                onEndedVid = document.getElementById("myVideo" + videoCount);

                var onEndedVid;
                onEndedVid.onended = function () {
                    //at the end of the video, close full screen
                    myHandler();
                };

                videoCount = videoCount + 1;

            }

            function myHandler() {

                if (videoCount == numVideos) {
                    //this is where we should switch from image div to video div
                    document.getElementById("container").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("VidDiv").style.display = "none";

                    location.reload();
                }
                else {
                    videoPlay(videoCount);
                }
            }
            myHandler();

        }
        else
        {
            ///back to images
            //refresh the page
            location.reload();
        }           
    }
}
```

Code behind:

```
// this will be a watcher that checks if is new content... if there is, delete the existing .wpl file and recreate the .wpl with new content links included        
    private void CreateNewPlayList(string folder)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            fileName = getDrive(folder) + @"\" + folder + "Playlist.wpl";
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);

            String f = @"<?wpl version=""1.0""?> 
           <smil>
           <head><meta name=""Generator"" content=""Microsoft Windows Media 
         Player -- 10.0.0.3646""/>   
           <author/>
          <title> a title goes here </title>
          </head>
          <body>
          <seq> ";
              String ff = @"
         </seq> 
         </body> 
         </smil>";
               using (FileStream fs = fileInfo.Create())
            {
                Byte[] txt = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(f);
                fs.Write(txt, 0, txt.Length);

                ////write paths and load only certain file types according to requirements into array
                String[] extentions = { "*.mp4", "*.wmv", "*.JPG".ToLower(), "*.ppt", "*.png" };

                List<string> files = new List<string>();

                foreach (string filter in extentions)
                {
                    files.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(getDrive(folder) + @"\", filter));
                }

                int filecount = files.Count;
                string[] video_lists = new string[files.Count];

                int counts = 0;
                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    video_lists[counts] = file.ToString();
                    string PathfileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
                    Byte[] author;
                    //use the ppt to be able to go into the folder and add each slide as part of the playlist
                    if (Path.GetExtension(PathfileName) == ".ppt" || Path.GetExtension(PathfileName) == ".pptx")
                    {
                        //create a loop to loop through the folder that has the same name as ppt/pptx(PathFileName)
                        string pptDrive = getDrive(folder) + @"\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(PathfileName) + @"\";
                        if (Directory.Exists(pptDrive))
                        {
                            string[] pptFilesFolder = Directory.GetFiles(pptDrive);
                            int counter = 1;
                            while (counter <= pptFilesFolder.Length)
                            {
                                foreach (string pptFile in pptFilesFolder)
                                {
                                    string pptFileName = Path.GetFileName(pptFile);
                                    string pptFileNameNoExt = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pptFile);                                                                         

                                    int i = pptFilesFolder.Length;
                                    int ss = Convert.ToInt16(new String(pptFileNameNoExt.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray()));
                                    if (ss <= i && ss == counter)
                                    {
                                        author = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(@"<media src=""" + pptDrive + @"\" + pptFileName + "\"/>");
                                        fs.Write(author, 0, author.Length);
                                        counter++;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //do something...
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        author = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(@"<media src=""" + getDrive(folder) + @"\" + PathfileName + "\"/>");
                        fs.Write(author, 0, author.Length);
                    }
                    counts = counts + 1;
                }

                Byte[] toptxt = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(ff);
                fs.Write(toptxt, 0, toptxt.Length);

            }

        }
        catch (IOException io)
        {
            //error handling....

            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //error handling...
            return;
        }
    }
```

The code can obviously be improved and optimized, but this is the base we used to get our app working. Thanks for all the advice and input!